# Pullback of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ via the degree $n$ map $\mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, pullback

Let $k$ be a field and consider the degree $n$ map $f: \mathbb P^1_k \to \mathbb P^1_k$ given by $(x:y) \mapsto (x^n: y^n)$.  I want to show that $f^*(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_k}(1)) \simeq \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_k}(n)$.

My attempt is as follows:  by definition, we have to calculate 
$$f^*(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_k}(1)) = f^{-1}(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_k}(1)) \otimes_{f^{-1}(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_k})} \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_k},$$ so we have to describe the sections of this sheaf over every affine open set $U = {\rm Spec}(R)$ and show that they agree with $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_k}(n)({\rm Spec}(R))$.  How to describe these sections?  I guess the sections of $f^{-1}(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_k}(1))({\rm Spec}(R)))$ given by rational functions of the form $g(x^n,y^n)/h(x^n,y^n) \in R(x,y)$ where $g(x,y)$ and $h(x,y)$ are homogeneous polynomials with $deg(g) - deg(h) = 1$; is this correct?  How to get this?  If this is true, then I guess we can compute the tensor product in the display above to get that $f^*(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1_k}(1))({\rm Spec}(R))$ consists of rational functions of the form $$\frac{g(x^n,y^n)}{h(x^n,y^n)} \cdot \frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)},$$ where $p$ and $q$ are homogeneous of the same degree.  But why are these all the rational functions $\frac{r(x,y)}{s(x,y)}$, where $r$ and $s$ are homogeneous with $deg(r)-deg(s)=n$?

Comment: You can use that the pullback of a line bundle is the line bunde associated with the pullback of the corresponding divisors. A generic point in $\Bbb P^1$ has $n$ preimages and you are done.

Comment: Pick a rational function $r/s$ of degree $n$ as above. Then $r/s = x^n \cdot r/(sx^n)$, a function of $x^n, y^n$ of degree $n$ times a degree-$0$ function, as desired.